# How to modify default visual studio generate dockerfile to include running SQLServer Linux?

Tags: sql-server, linux, docker, asp.net-core

I have been experimenting with docker to :

1.Create sql server linux containers
2.Adding docker support to existing .net core 2.1 app

When I add the docker support for existing app using visual studio, it generates the necessary default docker file to get the app up and running in container:

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-aspnetcore-runtime AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-sdk AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY RTMGMTCore2/RTMGMTCore2.csproj RTMGMTCore2/
RUN dotnet restore RTMGMTCore2/RTMGMTCore2.csproj
COPY . .
WORKDIR /src/RTMGMTCore2
RUN dotnet build RTMGMTCore2.csproj -c Release -o /app

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish RTMGMTCore2.csproj -c Release -o /app

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "RTMGMTCore2.dll"]
```

Is there any easy way to modify this file to include running of a SQL Server linux container to:

1.Bring up SQL server in same container?
2.Bring up SQL server in a different container?

Havent had luck so far with most existing examples out there, because they assume creating the dockerfile from scratch. My ultimate intent is to create a container to demo an the app and it is dependent on a sql server datasource- so I was thinking of maybe  an express version of sql server linux if that exists.

Anyone have a quick example of how to do this modifying the existing visual studio created default dockerfile?

Thanks!

Comment: You can use this container https://hub.docker.com/r/microsoft/mssql-server-linux/

Comment: thanks- yes i have been using that and can spin up sql server container no problem. Its integrating it with the  .net core app  that is the obstacle- either two separate containers - one spinning up the other or both app and sql server in same container seeing and recognizing each other.